# Workbox redirect the clients page when resource is not cached and offline

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

Usually whenever I read a blog post about PWA's, the tutorial seems to just precache every single asset. But this seems to go against the app shell pattern a bit, which as I understand is: Cache the bare necessities (only the app shell), and runtime cache as you go. (Please correct me if I understood this incorrectly)

Imagine I have this single page application, it's a simple index.html with a web component: `<my-app>`. That `<my-app>` component sets up some routes which looks a little bit like this, I'm using Vaadin router and web components, but I imagine the problem would be the same using React with React Router or something similar.

```js
router.setRoutes([
    {
        path: '/',
        component: 'app-main', // statically loaded
    },
    {
    path: '/posts',
        component: 'app-posts',
        action: () => { import('./app-posts.js');} // dynamically loaded
    },
    /* many, many, many more routes */
    {
        path: '/offline', // redirect here when a resource is not cached and failed to get from network
        component: 'app-offline', // also statically loaded
    }
]);
```

My app may have many many routes, and may get very large. I don't want to precache all those resources straight away, but only cache the stuff I absolutely need, so in this case: my `index.html`, `my-app.js`, `app-main.js`, and `app-offline.js`. I want to cache `app-posts.js` at runtime, when it's requested.

Setting up runtime caching is simple enough, but my problem arises when my user visits one of the potentially many many routes that is not cached yet (because maybe the user hasn't visited that route before, so the `js` file may not have loaded/cached yet), and the user has no internet connection.

What I want to happen, in that case (when a route is not cached yet and there is no network), is for the user to be redirected to the `/offline` route, which is handled by my client side router. I could easily do something like: `import('./app-posts.js').catch(() => /* redirect user to /offline */)`, but I'm wondering if there is a way to achieve this from workbox itself.

So in a nutshell:
When a `js` file hasn't been cached yet, and the user has no network, and so the request for the file fails: let workbox redirect the page to the `/offline` route.

Comment: have you looked at setCatchHandler? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.routing#.setCatchHandler and https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#provide_a_fallback_response_to_a_route

Comment: I have seen that, but then I'd still  have  to just return a response right? What Id like to  do is redirect the page to `/offline` from my service worker. Or is there a way  to do that  that im missing?

Comment: I have only set catch handlers for images, but the code example in the second link returns a fallback html url, I haven't tried that but it looks like it could work.

Comment: That doesn't really solve it though, my question is: when a request to this javascript file fails, can I, from the service worker, somehow make the client go to the `/offline` route? I guess I could return a (precached) `404.js` that just navigates to the `/offline` route, but it seems hacky. I'm wondering if theres a better/nicer way to handle this

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503761/whats-the-right-way-to-implement-offline-fallback-with-workbox?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1 (not always useful):**
As far as I can see and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34250261/7380613), you cannot open a new window or change the URL of the browser from within the service worker. However you can open a new window **only** if the `clients.openWindow()` function **is called from within** the `notificationclick` event.

**[Option 2](https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2016/url-navigation-from-service-worker/) (hardest):**
You could use the `WindowClient.navigate` method within the `activate` event of the service worker however is a bit trickier as you still need to check if the file requested exists in the cache or not.

**Option 3 (easiest & hackiest):**
Otherwise, you could respond with a new `Request` object to the offline page:

```js
const cacheOnly = new workbox.strategies.CacheOnly();
const networkFirst = new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst();

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /\/posts.|\/articles/, 
  async args => {
    const offlineRequest = new Request('/offline.html');

    try {
      const response = await networkFirst.handle(args);
      return response || await cacheOnly.handle({request: offlineRequest});

    } catch (error) {
      return await cacheOnly.handle({request: offlineRequest})

    }
  }
);
```

and then rewrite the URL of the browser in your `offline.html` file:

```html
 <head>
    <script>
        window.history.replaceState({}, 'You are offline', '/offline');
    </script>
 </head>
```

The above logic in **Option 3** will respond to the requested URL by using the network first. If the network is not available will fallback to the cache and even if the request is not found in the cache, will fetch the `offline.html` file instead. Once the `offline.html` file is parsed, the browser URL will be replaced to `/offline`.

Comment: This looks really promising! When I tried this, I'm getting a `The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:1117/app-posts-7f1dba0f.js" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().` error though, I tried a couple of things, but I can't seem to make it work... any ideas? (p.s. thanks for the spelling corrections :))

Comment: I was originally wrong about using `clients.openWindow` because it can only be used in some cases. I have updated the answer with more options.